# Draw trees with links between them

Tags: swt, jface

I'm developing a schema matching visualization tool. I have the problem that I have to draw trees and the links between them like this image:

[image]

However, the tool in the image uses Swing but I use JFace. 
Is there any visualization toolkit that support this ?

Comment: I am not aware of any toolkit for doing this but if I have to do it then I would explore the paint event. Remember you can calculate the location of the tree nodes and then draw a bezier curve/line between them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The two trees are JFace TreeViewer. How can I add another layer on top of these two trees to draw the line ? I think it has something to do with the z-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this a bit post is old, but it keeps coming up when I search for a solution to connect two nodes in JFace TreeViewer. On [JFace forum it was suggested](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/482295/) to look at [Nebula TreeMapper](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/treemapper/treemapper.php). Hope this helps someone.